# BASH: ssh access variable result on remote host

Tags: bash, ssh

How do I make a variable accessible on a remote computer via ssh?

I have a bash array containing *n* IP addresses for this specific instance I want to send the "result" of the first element in the array to the remote machine for further use.

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=(192.168.130.252 10.10.10.10 12.12.12.12)


echo "Before ssh: ${servers[0]}"
ssh ubuntu@"${servers[0]}" /bin/bash<<"EOF"
    echo "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')"
    echo "After ssh: ${servers[0]}"
    # MORE COMMAND HERE
EOF
exit 0

#Output
Before ssh: 192.168.130.252
192.168.130.252
After ssh:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have used quotes in `"EOF"`, ${servers[0]} gets expanded in remote shell, so to an empty string as array `servers` is not defined.
One way around is :

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=(192.168.130.252 10.10.10.10 12.12.12.12)

echo "Before ssh: ${servers[0]}"
ssh ubuntu@"${servers[0]}" CURRENT_HOST="${servers[0]}" /bin/bash<<"EOF"
    echo "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')"
    echo "After ssh: $CURRENT_HOST"
    # MORE COMMAND HERE
EOF
exit 0
```

Just found a way to send the whole array to remote shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=(192.168.130.252 10.10.10.10 12.12.12.12)

echo "Before ssh: ${servers[0]}"
{ declare -p servers
  cat << "EOF"
    echo "$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')"
    echo "After ssh: ${servers[0]}"
    # MORE COMMAND HERE
EOF
} | ssh ubuntu@"${servers[0]}" /bin/bash
```

Comment: Perfect, however is there a way to also send the complete array? Lets say that i have an ‘for loop for server in ${servers[\*]}‘ And want to send both ‘CURRENT=${server} ALL=${servers[\*]}’. Tested this however then I got an error every time thi array contained more then 1 item